# Не запускается программа после смены debug на release

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, mingw

Сменил сборку в qt с debug на release и при запуске приложения вылетает ошибка:

> Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc000007b). Для выхода из приложения
>   нажмите кнопку OK.

программа использует следующие dll:

```
Qt5Cored.dll
Qt5Networkd.dll
libzmq-v100-mt.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
```

Эти dll за исключением этой `libzmq-v100-mt.dll` я нашёл в папке `C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32` версии для win64 в установщике qt не было в принципе. Собственно как подлечить?

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <myservice.h>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <log.h>
#include <QDir>

#include "qthreadpoolserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();


//    MyService service(argc, argv);
//    return service.exec();
}
```

.pro файл

```
QT += core network
QT -= gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = test_agent
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle




CONFIG += warn_on

#win32 {
#message ("win32")
    LIBS += -lws2_32 -lkernel32 -lwevtapi -lshlwapi
    LIBS += -L"$$PWD/zeromq-2.2.0/bin" -lzmq-v100-mt
    DEFINES += "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600"
    include($$PWD\qtservice\src\qtservice.pri)
    include($$PWD\qtservice\common.pri)
#}
#unix {
#message ("unix")
#    LIBS += -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" -lzmq
#    include($$PWD/qtservice/src/qtservice.pri)
#    include($$PWD/qtservice/common.pri)
#}


QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_OFF += -Wno-pmf-conversions -Wpmf-conversions -Wcpp -Wwrite-strings
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF += -Wno-pmf-conversions -Wpmf-conversions -Wcpp -Wwrite-strings

QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_OFF += -Wunused-parameter
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF += -Wunused-parameter
QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON  -= -Wunused-parameter
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wunused-parameter


TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    myservice.cpp \
    log.cpp \
    qthreadpoolserver.cpp \
    qsocketrunnable.cpp \
    settings.cpp \
    crossplatformpath.cpp \
    senderthread.cpp \
    http_response_codes.cpp \
    agent_win/log_reader.cpp \
    agent_win/stringdata.cpp \
    agent_win/util.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/CharDistribution.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/JpCntx.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/LangBulgarianModel.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/LangCyrillicModel.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/LangGreekModel.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/LangHebrewModel.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/LangHungarianModel.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/LangThaiModel.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsBig5Prober.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsCharSetProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEscCharsetProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEscSM.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEUCJPProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEUCKRProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEUCTWProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsGB2312Prober.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsHebrewProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsLatin1Prober.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsMBCSSM.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsSBCharSetProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsSJISProber.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsUniversalDetector.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsUTF8Prober.cpp \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/charsetdetect.cpp \
    winlog.cpp \
    multithreadcontainer.cpp \
    my_zmq.cpp \
    crossplatformthread.cpp \
    filethread.cpp \
    syslogthread.cpp \
    crossplatformsources.cpp \
    unixthread.cpp




HEADERS += \
    myservice.h \
    log.h \
    qthreadpoolserver.h \
    qsocketrunnable.h \
    settings.h \
    crossplatformpath.h \
    senderthread.h \
    http_response_codes.h \
    agent_win/log_reader.h \
    agent_win/stringdata.h \
    agent_win/util.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/CharDistribution.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/JpCntx.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsBig5Prober.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsCharSetProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsCodingStateMachine.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEscCharsetProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEUCJPProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEUCKRProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsEUCTWProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsGB2312Prober.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsHebrewProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsLatin1Prober.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsMBCSGroupProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsPkgInt.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsSBCharSetProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsSBCSGroupProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsSJISProber.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsUniversalDetector.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/base/nsUTF8Prober.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/obsolete/protypes.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prcpucfg.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prcpucfg_freebsd.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prcpucfg_linux.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prcpucfg_mac.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prcpucfg_openbsd.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prcpucfg_win.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prmem.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nspr-emu/prtypes.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/charsetdetect.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/charsetdetectPriv.h \
    agent_win/charsetdetect/nscore.h \
    winlog.h \
    multithreadcontainer.h \
    my_zmq.h \
    crossplatformthread.h \
    filethread.h \
    syslogthread.h \
    crossplatformsources.h \
    unixthread.h

DISTFILES +=
```

Comment: 90% :) - где-то с памятью проблемы. Типа использования неинициализированной памяти или еще чего. В отладочном режиме такие вещи часто проскакивают...

Comment: скорее всего нет, потому что я упростил код до минимума и ничего. Добавил код в первый пост

Comment: Ну, я же не написал 100% :) Просто если debug работает, а release нет - то *обычно* это симптом проблем с инициализацией и памятью...

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, вот, почитайте - https://habrahabr.ru/post/127543/

Comment: Для релиза нужно использовать релизные библиотеки, для дебага -- дебажные. Qt5Cored.dll -- дебажная, Qt5Core.dll -- релизная. В дебажной к названию добавляется `d`

Answer (score 1):

Код ошибки 0xc000007b определен как [STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx):

> {Bad Image} %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it
>   contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original
>   installation media or contact your system administrator or the
>   software vendor for support.

Обычно причина в том, что DLL, которую пытается загрузить программа, повреждена или не соответствует разрядности приложения (32-битные приложения не могут использовать 64-битные DLL, и наоборот).

Применительно к Qt это скорее всего значит, что в отладочной конфигурации IDE принудительно подсовывает нужные библиотеки, а в релизном - нет, поэтому нужно убедиться, что в папке с программой лежат правильные версии библиотек. Для формирования распространяемого пакета приложения существует утилита [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). Для определения всех необходимых DLL можно использовать программы типа Dependency Walker.

Answer (score 0):

libzmq-v100-mt.dll по всей видимости - библиотека MSVC 10 версии. А у Вас проект mingw. Скорее всего вместе их использовать не получиться. Нужно искать libzmq-v100-mt.dll скомпилированную mingw, или же qt скомпилированный msvc 2010.
Попробуйте убрать эти строки из pro-файла:

```
LIBS += -lws2_32 -lkernel32 -lwevtapi -lshlwapi
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/zeromq-2.2.0/bin" -lzmq-v100-mt
DEFINES += "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600"
```

Затем запустить qmake и пересобрать проект.

Comment: Проверил, дело не в них

Comment: @Никола Кривошея тогда начинайте с того, что создайте пустой проект и пробуйте его запускать в Debug | Release режимах.